# Does SignalR Client run on .NET Compact Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, signalr

I haven't found any documentation on what platforms [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) supports, and would like to know whether SignalR Client runs on .NET Compact Framework?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SignalR .NET client is built the TPL (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(VS.100).aspx) and only works on .NET 4.0 and above. There was a .NET 3.5 version but we've deprecated it in the latest release. You can certainly write a client for the compact framework but we don't have plans to write one at the moment.

Comment: Sorry to hear you have deprecated the 3.5 version.

Comment: You can still get it in source we just never supported it officially.