# Does SignalR Server run on .NET Compact Framework?

Tags: c#, signalr, compact-framework

My question based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13856783/does-signalr-client-run-on-net-compact-framework) anwsered request from 2013. Is it possible to run a SignalR Server in an Windows Compact 2013 Envionment  with .Net Compact 3.9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the compact framework does not support ASP.NET, for which SignalR is a library.

Comment: thank you for answering. Do you know if it is planed to support, because of the growing count of IoT solutions? IMHO  it's missing at this point.

Comment: You could host a WebBrowser control and invoke the javascript client, a bit of a hack but could work

Comment: @ignos What exactly are you planning to do with your device? It is quite uncommon to host websites on a device.

Comment: i have a measuring unit which puts out some data each second. On the device is a Windows embedded compact 2013 installed. 
On client side i have several different kinds of technologies, such as javascript on a webpage, or a .net application.  
Would it be not a good solution to give the measuring unit a Service based on SignalR to provide and update the data?

Comment: @ignos You could use sockets to send/receive the data, they are supported by the compact framework and operate on a lower level than a web server.

Comment: @Evenhuis: yes, it might be an option.
but it could be more simple with SignalR, i think. There are several well tested clients-implementations available (.net, javascript), each with fallback mechanisms.  That could reduce the development expenses.